# ggplot boxplot for multiple columns with a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot2`, I want to plot boxplot of multiple numerical columns in the same plot, and group the boxplot by a factor from the last column the header of the dataframe is like:

```
id var1 var2 var3 factor
```

I know I can do:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=factor,y=var1)+geom_boxplot()
```

For each variable.

How can I plot them together with `ggplot2`? The base graphics utility `boxplot(df[,-c(id,factor)]` will plot them together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following works "to plot boxplot of multiple numerical columns in the same plot, and group the boxplot by a factor":

```
mm = melt(df, id=c('id','factor.col'))
ggplot(mm)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=paste(variable,factor.col,sep="_"), y=value))
```

[image]

Data:

```
> df
   id          var1       var2       var3 factor.col
1   1  0.0562941632  1.3055892 -1.7553986          c
2   2  0.3187487914 -0.6434729  0.7582403          a
3   3 -1.0120881740  0.3898366  0.4790115          c
4   4 -0.7576871261  0.9474247  0.2180341          b
5   5 -0.2895981608  0.2388043 -0.4407693          a
6   6  0.0005306311  0.9494667 -0.2604795          c
7   7  0.2022893934 -0.3095420 -1.9483369          c
8   8 -0.8179580833 -0.7891642  0.7662824          b
9   9 -0.7553554525  0.2734337 -0.7145471          b
10 10  0.4206429078 -0.6171774  0.6274320          c
>
```

Following can also be used:

```
ggplot(mm)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=variable, y=value))+facet_grid(.~factor.col)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that's what I want.

Comment: @ crazyhottommy: But then why have you accepted the other answer which does not show var1, var2 and var3?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ggplot2` the layout of your data needs to be a little different to how you would have it for the base graphics

```
#Your sample data...
df= data.frame(id = 1:10,
           var1 = rnorm(10),
           var2 = rnorm(10),
           var3= rnorm(10),
           factor.col= LETTERS[1:10]
)
# Use the reshape2 package to merge the columns by id and factor.col
library(reshape2)
df_long <- melt(df, id=c("id","factor.col"))
# And now plot the boxplots
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_long,aes(x=factor.col,y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
```